# add rosdep rule

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
because of [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/55701/trying-to-install-dependencies/), I would like to add a rosdep rule for octomap_mapping -> ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping. I went to the [rosdep page](http://ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) and read the instructions on how to do it. I created a github account, read the instructions there, forked the directory, added it to my local github sources, used google to find out how to use git to get a local checkout of a github repository and browsed through the rosdep/base.yaml and releases/fuerte.yaml.

Now I am stuck because I don't know how to add the rule. The existing octomap rules in releases/fuerte.yaml are cryptic to me and the rules in base.yaml never reference a ros-fuerte-xxx package. I am a bit frustrated about the time lost at the entry barrier. Any suggestions how to get it done quickly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55851/add-rosdep-rule/) by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6468 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If octomap is in releases/fuerte.yaml make sure you have the line:

```
gbpdistro https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml fuerte
```

in your rosdep sources

And make sure to set ROS_DISTRO=fuerte

Such that you will get the following:

```
$ ROS_DISTRO=fuerte rosdep resolve octomap
#apt
ros-fuerte-octomap
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0